# Initialize activity without displaying it on the screen in android?

Tags: android, service, xmpp, asmack

I am working on a chat XMPP application for android.
Using asmack client.

I am stuck in a problem where I am making the user logon to the server using service.

So now when the user gets logged on the server via service the activity containing friend list is displayed. 
This is the situation i want to avoid.

How can i initialize my friend list activity without displaying it?

Comment: some code? logcat? anything?

Comment: Can you post some code? What do you have in your manifest? Where the activity is started?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. From what i can understand if you dont want any user interface , u need not create an activity . Also if its regarding the visibility , you can switch the visibility of your list view based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your buddy list from the server once you've connected in your service, call

`connection.getRoster();`

This will return a Roster object. You can then perform operations utilizing the Roster object. For full documentation I recommend you visit the Java-docs on [Smack API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html)